# how to add CIFilters to a video at runtime

Tags: swift, video, filter, avfoundation, cifilter

I have recorded a video using avfoundation and after clicking on the video its start to play on a new viewcontroller. The problem is, I wouldn't be able to add filter effects to a playing video. Following is the code of what i have achieved.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class VideoPlayback: UIViewController {

    let avPlayer = AVPlayer()
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

    var videoURL: URL!

    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(finishVideo), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer.frame = view.bounds
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        videoView.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

        view.layoutIfNeeded()

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL as URL)
        avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

        avPlayer.play()

    }

    @objc func finishVideo()
        {
            print("Video Finished")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToFifteenSeconds", sender: self)
        }

// Remove Observer
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

}
```

Above code is only to play a video that was captured by the camera using AVfoundation. I only need to add CIfilters to this played video.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> you can apply a filter to a video

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
let asset = AVAsset(url: streamURL)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
item.videoComposition = AVVideoComposition(asset: asset,  applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in

    // Clamp to avoid blurring transparent pixels at the image edges
    let source = request.sourceImage.clampingToExtent()
    filter.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    // Vary filter parameters based on video timing
    let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime)
    filter.setValue(seconds * 10.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

    // Crop the blurred output to the bounds of the original image
    let output = filter.outputImage!.cropping(to: request.sourceImage.extent)

    // Provide the filter output to the composition
    request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
})
```

Comment: i don't get it, could you please tell me where i use this code, sorry for asking too much, basically i am new in ios.

Comment: Good answer. @Pratap

Comment: the code you gave works only for "CIGaussianBlur" filter. if i want to use another CIFilter, what do i do? @Pra

Comment: you can change filter name   it is simple  and  accept answer

Comment: In my case it didn't work. What can be issue that my it doesn't within the block on my case. It never reaches the line with ``let source = request.sourceImage...

Comment: Note this doesn't work with HLS :( "A video composition can only be used with file-based media and is not supported for use with media served using HTTP Live Streaming."